# What is adding a property to builtins module needed for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Looking inside NumPy source code I saw a [strange declaration](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/setup.py#L43) inside the `setup.py` file.

```py
# This is a bit hackish: we are setting a global variable so that the main
# numpy __init__ can detect if it is being loaded by the setup routine, to
# avoid attempting to load components that aren't built yet.  While ugly, it's
# a lot more robust than what was previously being used.
builtins.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = True
```

I understand this is a way to declare a constant so that it can be accessed from the main NumPy init. But what's the mechanism that makes this work? Looking to [NumPy's main init file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/__init__.py#L116-L121) you can see that it treats `__NUMPY_SETUP__` as if it was accessible, also if the file doesn't import the `builtins` module.

Comment: builtin namespace is always accessible (LEGB: local, enclosing, global, builtins).  It's just being used as a flag.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html

Comment: This is extremely hacky. Basically, the the built-in namespace is where all the built-in [functions and types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) are stored, e.g. `list`, `dict`, `sum` etc. That is why you never have to import anything to use them anywhere, the built-in namespace is checked after the global (i.e. module) namespace. This makes a name available anywhere. Generally, you shouldn't be messing with the built-in namespace. But as with many things that are usually not good ideas, Python won't *stop* you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is it something that should not be done because may cause problems, or just because it isn't good practice to pollute the built-in namespace?

Comment: Well, it *could cause problems* by accidentally mangling something in the built-in namespace, or it could accidentally hide a bug in some other module by making a name available which is an error. Both of these would be unlikely in this case. But to me, it just looks like a bad solution. Maybe it was the least bad of the available options, though.